# Popup on marker not working with Mapbox.js on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, popup, leaflet, mapbox, marker

I'm creating a map with Mapbox.js and I have a problem. I've added some markers to the map with a popup on each of them.
Testing this on Chrome Desktop it works well, when I click the marker it shows the popup. But when I'm trying to do the same on mobile (Android and iOS) it doesn't work at all. On mobile the popup is never shown when I touch on them.

Anyone know why is this happening? And how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post important parts of your code or even create a JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: Have you tried to emulate touch events on Chrome developer tools? You can see if you have any errors in the console when you click (touch) the markers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after trying a lot of things I found that my problem was generated by Ionic. 
So, I fixed with this:

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true">
<div id="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

You can read the docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/).